# Android Keyboard multiple image category with tab layout

Tags: java, android, keyboard

> how to get multiple images category in the android keyboard?

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: once user enable keyboard then open any social app for message and display multiple category images with tab layout after that user click images send directly to message